# The amount of disk used by each volume used in Amazon EC2 machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance with 2 EBS volumes (each 1000 GB), and I want to shrink their size to the proper size. The question is what is this "proper size".
Here is the locations of the volumes shown to me at the AWS page: 
[image]

When I login to the machine I get amount of space used, I get:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xxx-xxx ~]$ df -h 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1     1008G  194G  814G  20% /
devtmpfs         30G   60K   30G   1% /dev
tmpfs            31G     0   31G   0% /dev/shm
```

If I go inside the `/dev` and do `ls` (among lots of things) I would see that:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           5 Aug 20 00:50 root -> xvda1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           4 Aug 20 00:50 sda -> xvda
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           5 Aug 20 00:50 sda1 -> xvda1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root           4 Aug 20 00:49 sdf -> xvdf
```

- First, why inside `dev` we have `xvda`, `xvda1`, xvdf'? (and why `sda`, `sda1`?) The console only talks about `sdf` and `xvda`.
- Second, in the output of `df -h`, `/dev/xvda1` seems to be only one of the EBS volumes (right?) If so, how can get the disk usage for the other EBS volume?

Update: More info:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-144-183-22 ~]$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0    1T  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0 1024G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0    1T  0 disk 


[ec2-user@ip-10-144-183-22 ~]$ sudo fdisk -l | grep Disk
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.
Disk /dev/xvda: 1099.5 GB, 1099511627776 bytes, 2147483648 sectors
Disk label type: gpt
Disk /dev/xvdf: 1099.5 GB, 1099511627776 bytes, 2147483648 sectors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. These are virtual mounts. The operating system is responsible for the naming of the drive. For example: the public AMI for centos might show /dev/xvdc for sdb which is the primary drive.
2. You attached sdf, it shows as /dev/xvdf. It's not showing in `df -h` likely because it's not formatted and mounted. `fdisk -l` will likely show it. Format it and mount it, `df -h` will show it. If it is formatted, it's probably just not mounted.

Comment: So basically, if I understand correctly, if I detach `sdf` it shouldn't break anything in functionality; right?

Comment: That's hard to say without knowing your set up. I'd verify, but usually if it's not mounted it's fine to detach